# BIRT pagebreak depending on the data retrieved from the table

Tags: birt

There is a case when either of the table grows and I want that page to break at a certain point when the total row count (of both tables accumulated) grows beyond a certain point eg. 40.

Each page is designed as a grid 
Grid1 has two tables:

Table 1: I click on the table and go to the onCreate of script tab.

```js
table1 = this.getRowData().getExpressionValue('row[count]'); // row count contains the number of rows
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("table1", table1);
```

Table 2: I click on the table and go to the onCreate of script tab.

```js
table2 = this.getRowData().getExpressionValue('row[count1]');
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("table2", table2);
table1 = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("table1");
sum = table1 + table2;
if(sum > 30){
    this.getStyle().pageBreakBefore = "always";
}
```

Comment: Anyone with BIRT experience can please give some guidance,

Comment: I don't know if this is important, but instead of this.getRowData().getExpressionValue('row[count1]') you could just write row[count1] etc ...

Answer (score 0):

onCreate OF TABLE 2:

```
var totRowCountFromTbl1 = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("totRowCountTbl1");
log(" totRowCountFromTbl1 : "+totRowCountFromTbl1);

var totRowCountFromtbl2 = this.getRowData().getExpressionValue("row[Aggregation_1]");
log(" totRowCountFromtbl2 : "+totRowCountFromtbl2);

if(totRowCountFromTbl1 != 0){
    if(totRowCountFromtbl2 != 0){
        var sum = parseInt(totRowCountFromTbl1) + parseInt(totRowCountFromtbl2);
        if((sum >= 34) && (totRowCountFromTbl1 <= 33 )){
            this.getStyle().pageBreakBefore = "Always";
        }
    }
}
```